# What lenses are generally used to focus a beam of light into a horizontal line?

Tags: optics, laser, lenses

I am trying to find out more about the inner workings of a laser scanner I'm using to map objects. In this case the technical details are quite hard to come by. The laser scanner generates a beam of light which is projected in the shape of a line. The scanner then uses triangulation to determine the height of the object it's scanning. ([This](https://www.micro-epsilon.com/2D_3D/laser-scanner/?sLang=en) is the kind of scanner I'm using in this case)

Because I can't really find anything from the manufacturer about how that projection is created I was wondering what setup of lenses one would usually use to create a line like that. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I would guess something vaguely cylindrical to spread out the laser horizontally. Or, the laser may be rotating.

Comment: Hmm, seems like that might actually be the answer, the cylindrical lens i mean. The specs manual only mentions "using special lenses" so I thought they might need a setup of multiple lenses to create that effect. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, passing a laser through a horizontally curved lens will spread it out horizontally, but I'm sure the reality is more complex than that. Reality is always more complex than that. For example, how to get a uniform beam intensity? And a very wide beam?

Comment: I (layperson) think that actually, *most* lenses are special. All lenses are custom-designed - unless you buy one that's mass-produced for an unrelated purpose, which someone else custom-designed. So calling it "special" isn't really very informative.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [their documentation](https://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/products/cat--scanCONTROL--en.pdf), you will  read this:

> Laser scanners – often referred to as profile sensors – use the laser
> triangulation principle for  two-dimensional profile detection on
> different target surfaces. By using special lenses, a laser  beam is
> enlarged to form a static laser line and is projected onto the target
> surface. The receiving  optics projects the diffusely reflected light
> of this laser line onto a highly sensitive sensor matrix. In  addition
> to distance information (z-axis), the controller also uses this camera
> image to calculate  the position along the laser line (x-axis). These
> measured values are subsequently output in a  two-dimensional
> coordinate system that is fixed with respect to the sensor. In the
> case of moving  objects or a traversing sensor, it is therefore
> possible to obtain 3D measurement values.

The lens typically is either a cylindrical lens or a Fresnell cylindrical-focus lens.  Since the laser source could be either radially symmetric or elliptical (as is the case with most laser diodes),  the full lens system design is likely to be a bit more complicated and patented by the manufacturer.

Keep in mind that there are dynamic scanners as well which can drive the beam in one or 2 dimensions to produce any "drawn figure" desired.

Comment: Thanks! I probably should've mentioned I did read that specifications sheet. It contains basically all the information which is publicly available as far as I can tell. The illustrations seem to suggest there's two lenses in there, though by now I've figured you'd need at least four to create a constantly diverging line from a laser point source.